# Мешает ли запущенный update другим запросам

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, транзакции

Есть база postgresql.

Я планирую периодически (несколько раз или десятков раз в день) запускать в ней один update-запрос.

В запросе есть подзапрос с парой джойнов, из-за чего он работает достаточно долго (от 1 до 10 минут).

При этом в большинстве случаев количество изменяемых строчек не так велико, он просто их долго ищет. Но время от времени между вызовами запроса может накапливаться и достаточно большое количество строк, подлежащих изменению (сотни тысяч).

Запрос выполняется не в транзакции.

Мой вопрос в том, не будет ли это мешать работе других задач, работающих с базой?

Что будет, если во время этих 1-10 минут кто-то захочет прочитать строчку, которая подпадает под условие этого запроса? Что будет, если кто-то поменяет строчку? Что будет, если кто-то возьмёт блокировку на строчку, или поменяет её в своей транзакции?

Стоит ли вообще запускать такие большие апдейты?

Если нет, то как лучше поступить?
Будет ли польза, если в существующий подзапрос вставить limit, и запускать запрос несколько раз, пока всё не проапдейтится?

Comment: Не знаю как в postgres, но обычно это зависит от уровня изоляции. Хотя и от конкретной реализации БД это тоже зависит. Даже запросы на чтение могут блокировать как отдельные записи, так и таблицы целиком. Пока таблица заблокирована, в неё никто не сможет ничего записать. Вообще да - лучше не делать долгие запросы, особенно в которых обновления происходят. По возможности, можно хотя бы писать что-то во временные таблицы и дальше с этими временными таблицами ещё что-то делать, чтобы не лочить таблицы в основной базе. И в конце уже результат из какой-то временной таблицы записывать в БД.

Comment: И да, если есть возможность ограчинить число обновляемых за раз записей и это позволит сильно сократить время работы одного запроса к базе, то это хорошо, надо так и делать. Если при этом не вырастет сильно суммарное время всего запроса, разбитого на такие части.

Comment: И ещё - почему "долго ищет"? Возможно, вам нехватает каких-то индексов в таблицах. Ну, либо вы не оптимально спроектировали базу в целом. Если есть возможность добавить в таблицы индексы, благодаря которым поиск будет идти гораздо быстрее - сделайте это, возможно, этого будет уже достаточно, чтобы запросы выполнялись гораздо быстрее и не мешали работе с базой других клиентов/приложений. Но помните, что индексы требуют места для хранения и несколько замедляют запись в таблицы с индексами.

Comment: @CrazyElf, по всем полям, по которым происходят джойны, индексы уже есть. Базу проектировал не я, и ничего принципиально менять в её структуре не могу.

Comment: Ну, индексы могут быть, но быть при этом не оптимальными. Например, есть индекс по одному полю отдельно, по другому полю отдельно, а джойн происходит сразу по нескольким полям. Большинство БД в этом случае использует только один какой-то индекс, а создание индекса по двум полям сразу позволит ускорить джойн. Если у вас там джойны не по текстовым полям, то я бы посмотрел план запросов и попытался всё же индексы пооптимизировать. Хоть индексы то вы можете добавлять или хоть предлагать добавлять? Ну либо забирать всё во временные таблицы и делать там какие нужно индексы.

Answer (score 1):

> Запрос выполняется не в транзакции.

Это невозможно в postgresql. Если вы не запрашивали транзакцию сами - она всё равно будет на время выполнения запроса.

> Что будет, если во время этих 1-10 минут кто-то захочет прочитать
>   строчку, которая подпадает под условие этого запроса?

Только прочитать - читайте на здоровье. MVCC позволяет читать данные пока кто-то другой их пишет. При том актуальной для читателя версии согласно изоляции транзакций. Если читать с `FOR UPDATE` - см. ответ про конкурентное обновление.

> Что будет, если кто-то поменяет строчку?

Важный вопрос "когда".

- после того как долгий запрос взял блокировку на эту строку - будет ждать завершение этого долгого запроса и только потом сможет обновить строку
- до того как долгий запрос взял блокировку - обновит. Долгий запрос возьмёт последнюю зафиксированную версию строки для update в Read committed (Read uncommitted в postgresql нет, если запросите то будет использован Read committed - это допустимо по стандарту) или даст ошибку сериализации в Repeatable read или Serializable

Если конкурентный запрос обновляет больше одной строки - большой риск поймать deadlock с отменой одной из двух конфликтующих транзакций (какой именно? той, которая заметит дедлок раньше, т.е. как повезёт)

> Стоит ли вообще запускать такие большие апдейты?

Зависит от требований к системе. Для OLAP - здорово что запрос такой быстрый. Для OLTP - будет больно из-за ожидания блокировок.

Обычные практики для такой аналитики:

- обновлять частями
- посчитать данные во временную табличку `create temp table as select ...` долгим запросом, затем помержить нужные данные в целевую табличку более быстрыми запросами

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от уровня изоляции транзакций. Глобально существует 4 уровня изоляции транзакций:

1. Read uncommitted
2. Read committed
3. Repeatable read
4. Serializable

Отличаются возможностью чтения/доступа к 3-м разным видам некорректных данных:

- **Dirty Reads** - чтение записей не прошедших коммит (1 уровень)
- **Nonrepeatable Reads** - чтение одной и той же записи несколько раз (1-2 уровни)
- **Phantoms** - чтение не существующих записей (1-2-3 уровни)

То есть если у вас уровень изоляции установлен `READ_UNCOMMITTED` - вы потенциально словите все 3 возможных некорректных данных, но транзакции будут проскакивать очень быстро

Если же уровень изоляции будет `SERIALIZABLE` - то все данные будут консистентны, но очень медленно.

Выбирать между скоростью и целостностью данных только вам.